# Python3 multiprocessing out of memory problem

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-3.8

my computer hangs while doing file processing (more than 10k) with multiprocessing programming. How can I solve this?

My computer has 8 cores and I couldn't solve this problem. Please help ^^

```
def execute_command(runcommand):
    child = Popen(runcommand.split(' '),stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
    try:
        child.wait(timeout=TIMEOUT)
    except Exception as e:
        child.kill()
    return child.returncode



def worker():
    file = #generate file list 
    for i in file:
        cmd = ''.join(['/usr/bin/blab','params',i])
        res = execute_command(cmd)

def main():
    a = []
    for _ in range(4):
        p = Process(target=worker)
        a.append(p)
        p.start()
    
    for i in a:
        i.join()

main()
```

Comment: if you can shift to using `multiprocessing.Pool`, there's an in-built `maxtasksperchild` parameter which limits the lifetime of each child in order to clean up any potential memory leaks within the child. Otherwise you'll need to give us more details...

Comment: @Aaron how can i do this? can you share sample code?

Comment: [Python Code](https://www.codepile.net/pile/MEo8N1Qm)

I did this but is it correct? I see more than 4 processes and some of them have 5 threads under them, is it normal? @Aaron

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your use case, each child process may be leaking resources as it runs (hard to tell from example code), and it may be beneficial to periodically re-start the child processes in order to allow the OS to collect un-used memory. `multiprocessing.Pool` has a built-in mechanism to do this for you (no sense in re-inventing the wheel) by specifying the argument `maxtasksperchild`. This is how you would re-write your example to take advantage of that:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def execute_command(i):
    runcommand = ''.join(['/usr/bin/blab','params',i]) #move this to the child target function
    child = Popen(runcommand.split(' '),stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
    try:
        child.wait(timeout=TIMEOUT)
    except Exception as e:
        child.kill()
    return child.returncode

def main():
    file = #generate file list 
    with Pool(4, maxtasksperchild=10) as pool: #more tasks per child could mean more memory usage, but fewer tasks per child means more overhead to keep re-creating child processes
        pool.map(execute_command, file)

if __name__ == "__main__": #always use this to prevent multiprocessing code from running on import
    main()
```